# read xml file using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i have the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Users>
    <User>
        <Name>John Smith</Name>
        <test>
            <Date>23.05.2011</Date>
            <points>33</points>
        </test>
        <test>
            <Date>22.06.2011</Date>
            <points>29</points>
        </test>
    </User>
</Users>
```

and i would like to use linq to extract the dates and the points of the tests where username is "John Smith"..

how would i build my linq ?

i have done the following, but is not working as i wish :

```
XElement main = XElement.Load(@"users.xml");

string t = "John Smith";
var v = from user in main.Elements("User")
        where t == users.Element("Name").Value
        select users;

MessageBox.Show(v.First().Element("Date").Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile. You're using `users` where you should use `user`. And you have typo in your `t` initialization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what format you want the output to be, but this samples code should get the date and points.  This projects the results into an anonymous type:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XElement main = XElement.Load(@"users.xml");

        var results = main.Descendants("User")
            .Descendants("Name")
            .Where(e => e.Value == "John Smith")
            .Select(e => e.Parent)
            .Descendants("test")
            .Select(e => new { date = e.Descendants("Date").FirstOrDefault().Value, points = e.Descendants("points").FirstOrDefault().Value });

        foreach (var result in results)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", result.date, result.points);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
23.05.2011, 33
22.06.2011, 29
```

Comment: GREAT ..thank you

how would i insert a new "in this example a third" <Test> node with date and points to that user (John Smith) in the xml file ?

Answer (score 1):

```
XDocument main = XDocument.Load(@"users.xml"); 

string t = "John Smith"; 
var v = from user in main.Descendants("User") 
    where t == user.Element("Name").Value 
    select user; 

MessageBox.Show(v.First().Element("Date").Value.ToString());
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XElement main = XElement.Parse(
@"<Users>
    <User>
        <Name>John Smith</Name>
        <test>
            <Date>23.05.2011</Date>
            <points>33</points>
        </test>
        <test>
            <Date>22.06.2011</Date>
            <points>29</points>
        </test>
    </User>
</Users>");

        var users =
           from m in main.Elements("User")
           where (string)m.Element("Name") == "John Smith"
           select (m.Descendants("test").Descendants("Date").FirstOrDefault().Value);
        foreach (var user in users)
            Console.WriteLine(user);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

And about your other question to add another node to John Smith, this would be the solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XElement main = XElement.Parse(
    @"<Users>
       <User>
            <Name>Alex</Name>
            <test>
                <Date>08.05.2011</Date>
                <points>4</points>
            </test>
        </User>
        <User>
            <Name>John Smith</Name>
            <test>
                <Date>23.05.2011</Date>
                <points>33</points>
            </test>
            <test>
                <Date>22.06.2011</Date>
                <points>29</points>
            </test>
        </User>
    </Users>");


    var users =
       from m in main.Elements("User")
       where (string)m.Element("Name") == "John Smith"
       select (m.Descendants("test").Descendants("Date").FirstOrDefault().Value);

    XElement Mercury = main.Elements("User").Where(p => (String)p.Element("Name") == "John Smith").FirstOrDefault();
    Mercury.Add(new XElement("test", new XElement("Date", "06.06.2011"), new XElement("points", "01")));

    foreach (var user in main.Elements())
        Console.WriteLine(user);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

}

Giving the next expected result:

```
<User>
  <Name>Alex</Name>
  <test>
    <Date>08.05.2011</Date>
    <points>4</points>
  </test>
</User>
<User>
  <Name>John Smith</Name>
  <test>
    <Date>23.05.2011</Date>
    <points>33</points>
  </test>
  <test>
    <Date>22.06.2011</Date>
    <points>29</points>
  </test>
  <test>
    <Date>06.06.2011</Date>
    <points>01</points>
  </test>
</User>
```